# How to get current selection value from cake php FormHelper

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to modify some code in cakePHP and the last thing that is holding me still is my inability to get current value from input form and send it to my jquery script.

The forms look like this:

```
   <?php echo $this->Form->input('country', array('options' => $countriesOption, 'onchange' => 'getHotels(this.value, $(\'showSingleInput\').checked);', 'style' => 'margin: 10px;', 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'error' => 'false', 'hiddenField' => false, 'id' => 'countryInput')); ?>
   <?php 
   if($regionOption != null){
        echo $this->Form->input('region', array('options' => $regionOption, 'onchange' => 'getHotelsInRegion(this.value,this.value, $(\'showSingleInput\').checked);', 'style' => 'margin: 10px;', 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'error' => 'false', 'hiddenField' => false, 'id' => 'regionInput')); 
    }?>
```

The problems is at second input form 'region'.

I need to pass as first value to JQuery method currently selected value from 'country' form input.

And all the hard stuff I need to do is here:

```
'getHotelsInRegion(this.value,this.value, $(\'showSingleInput\').checked);'
```

Comment: If you already use jQuery, why using onchange? You chould just leverage jQuery to attach those methods. Also, for readability: Use CSS to style your inputs (using classes and ids).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$('#ModelNameFieldName').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

should to the trick.